# Testing async action creator that fetches some data from a local JSON file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, redux, jestjs

I am trying to use jest to test an async action creator that fetches some data. I have scavenged through the redux-mock-store documentation but I actually did not grasp what I should do. Here is action:

```
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

export interface Task {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  categoryTitle?: string;
  error?: null;
}

export interface Category {
  name: string,
  tasks: Task[]
}

export const getCategories = () => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const response = await axios.get<Category[]>(url);

    dispatch<GetCategoriesAction>({
      type: ActionTypes.getCategories,
      payload: response.data
    });
  };
};
```

How can I test it? Can someone guide me through the steps?

Answer (score 0):

You won't need `redux-mock-store` here.
Essentially, you would just mock axios (there's plenty of information on how to do that) and in your test call `getCategories()(dispatch)` with an instance of `jest.fn()` as dispatch. 
Then just test how often and with which arguments `dispatch` is being called for the different scenarios like "axios succeeded" or "axios failed".

The nice thing about redux is that it decouples things.

After that, you can test your reducers by calling them with a row of actions and `expect` what they return.

The nice thing about redux is that it separates these layers from each other, no need to test everything at once.

Comment: Thank you but can you give a code example on how can I do this? I am just newbie to all of these things and I'd appreciate a written code example to see.